# Substituir propriedade Text de Edit. Como?

Tags: delphi

Estou desenvolvendo um componente que é descendente de um `TEdit`. Ao chamar pela aplicação a propriedade `Text` desse componente, não quero que retorne o que está aparecendo efetivamente no `Text` do componente, antes quero montar um novo valor da propriedade `Text`.
Exemplo: `ShowMessage(Componente.Text)`.
Nesse caso, apesar da propriedade `Text` do componente possuir o valor **Olá mundo**, quero que apresente, por exemplo, o valor da propriedade `Hint` do componente.

Estou fazendo isso porque já possuo um componente de pesquisa que em todo o sistema, uso o `Text` como valor para operações (*SQL´s e etc.*) Agora estamos modernizando o mesmo, porém como todo o sistema o usa, preciso manter a mesma forma de acessá-lo, caso contrário, terei um trabalho gigantesco (quase impossível) para modernizar o componente.

Como fazer isso?

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: poderia explicar melhor a sua questão?

Comment: @Tmc Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: vamos ver se entendi quando fizer um ShowMessage(Componente.Text) quer na verdade que ele faça um ShowMessage(Componente.hit) mas não codigo tem de ter desta forma ShowMessage(Componente.Text)

Comment: @Tmc Isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver.
Criei uma propriedade Text com o *Read/Write* **GetText** e **SetText**.
No **GetText** faço que o `Result` receba o valor que quero, por exemplo o `Hint`, e se quiser o valor padrão, faço `Result := Inherited Text;`
E no **SetText**, faço assim: `inherited Text := Value;`

Comment: muito bem jovem